# The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: reporting-services, certificate

I read this blog post.
http://blogs.msdn.com/microsoftbob/archive/2009/08/20/a-wrapper-for-running-sql-server-2008-reporting-services-reports-anonymously.aspx
We have a similar solution that we have been using for a year now.  We are using IReportServerConnection2 interface implementation to provide the credentials to the report server directly.
Since last few months, we get this error randomly.

> The underlying connection was closed.  Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TSL channel.  Inner Exception: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

We have always used SSL and it does work for most of the day. The interesting thing is when we get this error, we just go to web.config of our ASP.NET app and change the timestamp of the file - the reportviewer starts working again.

The SSL certificate is valid and the reports are displayed most of the times. But once we get this error, we have to change web.config to get this to work again.

Any ideas. I appreciate your help.

Comment: has anyone run into this issue?

Comment: What kind of certificate are you using? Self-signed? Signed via public CA?